# Getting existing mapreduce job from cluster (the job could be running or completed)

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

Previously, I was using `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient#getJob(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID)` to get the `RunningJob` . This call was made from the job completion callback method, however, seems to me that there is a timing issue where if the job is already completed then the above `getJob()` method cannot find it and returns null. I can confirm that the job was completed from the cluster UI.

Keeping the `RunningJob` apart, is there a way to get the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` object of a mapred job given the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobID` , regardless whether the job is currently running or is completed?

I tried to code up something like:

`Cluster cluster = jobClient.getClusterHandle();
Job job = cluster.getJob(JobID.forName(jobId));
log.info("Trying to get actual job with id {} , found {} on cluster {}", JobID.forName(jobId), job, cluster);`

I can see the right jobId, and can also see the cluster object.. but the `cluster.getJob()` method returns null, so the job itself is null.

Is there something that I'm missing out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with with a recent yarn upgrade that required enabling MR history server on my system. This fixed the issue. I recently upgraded from MR v1 to v2 and in that upgrade, all completed jobs are now moved to the history server.

Answer (score 1):

You look for `getAllJobStatuses()` that return `JobStatus[]`:

```
  List<JobStatus> runningJobs = new ArrayList<JobStatus>();
  List<JobStatus> completedJobs = new ArrayList<JobStatus>();
  for (JobStatus job : cluster.getAllJobStatuses()) {
    if (!job.isJobComplete()) {
      runningJobs.add(job);
    }
    else {
      completedJobs.add(job)
    }
  }

  // list of running JobIDs
  for (JobStatus rjob : runningJobs) {
        System.out.println(rjob.getJobID().toString());
  }
  // list of completed JobIDs
  for (JobStatus cjob : completedJobs) {
        System.out.println(cjob.getJobID().toString());
  }

  // to print out short report on running jobs:
  // displayJobList(runningJobs.toArray(new JobStatus[0]));
```

Comment: I don't need running jobs.. I need an API that can return both running as well as completed jobs..

Comment: This can be obtained via getAllJobStatuses(). I made the edit that separates running jobs from completed ones.

Comment: I need the mr counters for completed jobs.